# Check if an array is empty or not - Postman - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the response in this format:

```
{
    "test1": [],
    "test2": [],
    "test3": [],
    "test4": null,
    "test5": []
}
```

After sending a request, this is the response i get.

And i want to check f. ex. does `test1` is empty or not.

And if it is empty it's enough to just console log.

Comment: Check for the length of the array..

Comment: pm.expect(yourJsonData.test1.length).to.eql(0);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you are looking for this . using `.length` property of the array

```js
let response = 
{
    "test1": [],
    "test2": [],
    "test3": [],
    "test4": null,
    "test5": []
}

if(response){
    if(response.test1 && response.test1.length == 0)
    {

      console.log("array empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be like `response.test1 && response.test1.length`

Comment: @Ved that was not the context of this question, here it is given that "test1" already exists so checking the length is enough also your condition will provide the message if the array exists and it's not empty but in question it was asked to check if the array is empty and log it.

Comment: Exeption always need to be handled.

Comment: @Niladri I think you should also include Ved's answer because existence should also be checked before using the length property.

Comment: @AlexRoy I have updated

Answer (score 0):

use javascript array.length  property.

```
  if(test1.length){
  //if array is not empty do something here
 }
 else{
       //array is empty..do something else

  {
```

Answer (score 0):

you should run something like this

```
if (response){
    if (response["test1"] && response["test1"].length>0){
        //do stuff
    }

    if (response["test2"] && response["test2"].length>0){
        //do stuff
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let response = 
{
 "test1": [],
 "test2": [],
 "test3": [],
 "test4": null,
 "test5": []
}

if(response){
   // in your case, test4 is null, so you need to check if null value too
   // try console.log(response['test4'] === response['test1']) // should be false
   if(response.testX.length && response.testX !== null)
   {
      console.log("You're awesome!");
   }
}
```